# When is the right time to change my company?

Tags: work-environment, career-development, work-experience, company-culture, resignation

I am currently working for a company as an engineer, I graduated in 2014 and it has been  6 months and a half since I started  working for this company. During this 6 months the only thing that took my attention is that a lot of employees stay at a maximum of 2 to 3 years before they decide to change companies.

So I keep thinking that one day I should change companies. Perhaps there something that they discovered through the years but now I could not discover it?

Can you please help me understand this phenomenon, yes its a phenomenon for me because when a lot of people keep doing something for a long time it is then a phenomenon?

When is the right time for me to start thinking bout changing the company?

Thank you all

Comment: People leave a company for any number of reasons. Some leave after 6 months because they don't like their boss and some stay with the company for 30 years. This question is far too broad and opinion-based, so I'm voting to close.

Comment: You are asking a question, whose answer is "It depends". You are leaving out too many variables, such as "is the company treating you fairly?", "is the company having trouble meeting the payroll?", "is the company closing down?", etc.

Comment: Agree to the comments above, the answer could be as trivial as "more salary at other companies". The answer could also be much more extensive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience, (3.5 years, and just changing job for the first time...), people seldom change company because they just think 2/3 years is a good time to change.

The main reasons for changing are:

- Better opportunity : Workers are sometimes offered opportunities even when they don't actively look for a new position. Then it starts them thinking that they might want to accept it, in order to discover something new and interesting and/or because the position offers more money (simplifying, but in essence)
- Dissatisfaction : Workers who are quite unsatisfied with their job or company actively look for a job. For a number of reasons, the 2/3 years time is kind of appropriate : they can change without looking like a job hopper, and this is also often the time when you find the limits of your position. So if they are not offered a move/promotion within the company, they start looking out.

### My own experience :

As I entered my previous company, everything looked nice, every collegue was great and the job was interesting. People were leaving and complaining and I could not understand why. After 2 years, I was in the position of being unhappy and complaining about it. And nothing actually changed in-between. Just that I got to know the environment, people and company culture better, and I slowly understood I needed to leave eventually.

However, my main point is : don't start thinking of leaving just because other people do that. You will feel when "it's time". If you are happy in your job and you still enjoy it, don't ask yourself this kind of questions. Grass isn't always greener...

Comment: This is the kind of an answer i was looking for, thank you @Puzzled

Answer (score 2):

High turnover rates are usually indicative of problems in a company, however that is not always the case. (And honestly, 2-3 years isn't terrible in a lot of industries.)

The short answer is that nobody can tell you when it's the right time to leave--that's entirely up to you. If you still like the company, if you enjoy the atmosphere, then stay. You might very well leave them in 3 years, but why worry about that now? Especially since this job is likely your first post-graduate job. No point in jumping ship over what-ifs.